# why android uses inner classes so much?

Tags: android

this is a general question. in all examples of android you find adapters, tasks or anything else as an inner class. Is that a best practice in android?

I know that make it easier to handle ui changes, but on the other site that makes large files.

Is there any rules in android where we could encapsulate those in seperate files or include it as an inner class?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: an inner, non-static class has access to everything in its parent instance, which makes it less cumbersome than an external class.

Comment: this is true but it's important to keep track of where you actually use inner classes cause they keep a reference to the parent class and, in the case of an android app, if the parent class is a sub-class of context it's important to be sure that after onDestroy() is called the reference disapper to let the GC clean up the context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not Android but its Java

From Java Oracle Docs:

> Why Use Nested Classes?
>
> There are several compelling reasons for using nested classes, among
>   them:
>
> > It is a way of logically grouping classes that are only used in one place.
> >
> > It increases encapsulation.
> >
> > Nested classes can lead to more readable and maintainable code.
> >
> > Logical grouping of classes—If a class
> >     is useful to only one other class, then it is logical to embed it in
> >     that class and keep the two together. Nesting such "helper classes"
> >     makes their package more streamlined.
> >
> > Increased encapsulation—Consider two top-level classes, A and B, where
> >     B needs access to members of A that would otherwise be declared
> >     private. By hiding class B within class A, A's members can be declared
> >     private and B can access them. In addition, B itself can be hidden
> >     from the outside world.
> >
> > More readable, maintainable code—Nesting small classes within
> >     top-level classes places the code closer to where it is used.